# On the Wishart distribution

Tags: inference, covariance, covariance-matrix, sample, wishart-distribution

### Definitions

Consider the following bivariate model
\begin{equation*}y\triangleq S(p)h+v\end{equation*}
where

- $p\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}\theta & \ell_1 & \ell_2\end{bmatrix}'$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, $\ell_1,\ell_2\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
- \begin{equation*}S(p)\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ell_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \ell_2\end{bmatrix}\end{equation*}
- $p$ is a modelled as a Gaussian random vector with generic expectation $p_{-}$ and generic covariance $P_{-}\geq 0$
  \begin{equation*}p\sim \mathcal{N}\left(p_{-}, P_{-}\right)\end{equation*}
- $h$ and $v$ are bivariate Gaussian noises, uncorrelated from each other and
  \begin{equation*}h\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, R_h\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/4\end{bmatrix}\right)\end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}v\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, R_v>0\right)\end{equation*}
- $p$ is not correlated with $h$ or $v$

consider the following sample of $m$ observations of $y$
\begin{equation*}y^{(j)}=S(p)h^{(j)}+v^{(j)} \qquad j =1,2,\dots, m\end{equation*}
and the relative sample covariance
\begin{equation*}S\triangleq \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m (y^{(j)}-\bar{y})(y^{(j)}-\bar{y})' \end{equation*}
where $\bar{y}\triangleq 1/m \sum_{j=1}^m y^{(j)}$ is the sample mean.

### Question

What is the distribution of $S$?
It would be useful also an approximation of the distribution.

### Observation

If we replace $S(p)$ with a deterministic matrix $A$ then $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0, AR_hA'+R_v)$, consequently, due to the uncorrelations between the observations $y^{(j)}$, we can say that $S$ follows a bivariate Wishart distribution with $m-1$ degrees of freedom and scale matrix $(AR_hA'+R_v)/(m-1)$.
\begin{equation*}S\sim\mathcal{W}_2\left(m-1, \frac{AR_hA'+R_v}{m-1}\right)\end{equation*}

### My unsatisfying solution

Actually I know a linearized model of $y$ in the following form
\begin{equation*}y\approx S(p_{0})h+J_p (p-p_{0})+v\end{equation*}
where $p_0$ is the center of the linearization and $J_p$ is the Jacobian of $S(p)h$ evaluated at $p_0$.
I'm considering $p_0=p_{-}$ as the center of the linearization.
Moreover, I know the covariance $\Sigma_y$ of the linearized model, which is in the form
\begin{equation*}\Sigma_y \triangleq \Sigma_{Sh}+R\end{equation*}
where $\Sigma_{Sh}$ is an approximation of the covariance of the term $S(p)h$ around $p_0=p_{-}$. In my simulations, this approximation seems to be accurate.

I'm supposing that the sample covariance $S$ is Wishart with $m-1$ degrees of freedom and scale matrix $\Sigma_y/(m-1)$.
\begin{equation}S\sim\mathcal{W}_2\left(m-1, \frac{\Sigma_y}{m-1}\right)\tag{1}\end{equation}
in my simulation this distribution seems to be accurate only for small numbers of $m$ (e.g up to $m=5$).
Since I consider $\Sigma_y$ accurate, I believe that the source of error is the term $S(p)h$, which, if I'm not wrong, correlate the observations $y^{(1)}$, ..., $y^{(m)}$, and so the Wishart distribution does not hold.
However, I don't understand why as $m$ grows the Wishart distribution $(1)$ deviates more and more from the empirical distribution of $S$.